# Tikz Flowchart Fill types: Hatched, dotted etc.,

Tags: tikz-pgf, fill

Is it possible to have hatched or dotted fill in the flowchart using Tikz.

For example, see the image below,  [image: A simple filling type]

If anyone knows any other type of filling other than just shaded fill, please share it.

Comment: Hi Mohanraj! Do you have a MWE? Where are you exactly stuck?

Comment: I am sorry I do not understand what MWE is.

If you are asking about the code, Here is an example...

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!30]
...
\node(test)[block]{Fill = green  ! 30}
...
Well, I am actually not stuck anywhere. I would like to know is there another way of filling the blocks in Latex, Tikz.

Thank you for your quick response :)

Comment: This is a [MWE-minimum working example](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/201158)

Comment: See `pgfmanual sec. 63 Pattern Library`

Comment: That's the answer I am looking for Thanks @ZhiyuanLck

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @ZhiyuanLck for this answer.
Here is a minimum working example,

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, patterns}

\tikzstyle{block} = [rectangle, minimum width=3cm, minimum height=1cm, text centered, text width=3cm, draw=black, pattern color=blue, pattern = north east lines]

\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance =2cm]
  \node (test) [block] {\textbf{Hashed Fill}} ;
  \end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Reference: http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf
Section 42: Pattern Library.